# Is it possible to reformat the following date entry?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Currently I am importing table information from a CSV file into Access, the CSV file formats its dates like "20190128" or "yyyymmdd" is it possible to somehow have Access reformat this data as "mm/dd/yy" ?

Comment: Like 10/11/12. Which can be 2010 November 12, or October 11, 2012, or 10:th of Nobemer 2012, or ... Keep YYYYMMDD!

Comment: Ok, maybe I will leave it but is it at all possible to add " / " to separate the values from each other?

Comment: I'd go with the common `YYYY-MM-DD` format, as specified by ISO-8601, and also ANSI SQL!

Comment: Why would you do that?  You have a nice standard unambiguous date format.  You can reformat it when you want to output it.  But store the value either as a YYYYMMDD string or as a `date` data type (of the two, the latter is much preferable).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use excel, it assumes your date is in cell A1:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),LEFT(A1,2))
```

create a new column with de 'formatted' date then export as csv. New column will be correctly interpreted as date

Answer (score 0):

You can use *CDate* and *Format* to obtain a date value:

```
TrueDate = CDate(Format([TextDate], "@@@@\/@@\/@@"))
```

Then apply the display form on TrueDate when needed.